# Android Studio - emulator process has been terminated

Tags: android-studio, emulator

I am getting this error whenever I am launching AVD:

```
The emulator process for AVD has terminated.
```

I have already checked possible solutions on YouTube, Stack Overflow, Superuser and whatnot but none of them seem to work for me.

I have already checked below and it did not work

- Available space in drives
- HAXM installer is also installed
- Already tried deleting the AVDs
- Checked the api version
- what else.. yes Emulator launch in a tool window - check uncheck done.

Prior to this error, I was getting error `timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online`. I guess I made some change and got this new error. Not sure if I have gone even backwards.

My OS - Windows 8, Android Studio version: Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1

Here you can see the logs from idea.txt

```
2023-02-08 17:58:05,095 [3915750]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 28 - C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_6_API_28
2023-02-08 17:58:05,142 [3915797]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 28 - Android emulator version 31.3.15.0 (build_id 9456632) (CL:N/A)
2023-02-08 17:58:05,157 [3915812]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 28 - emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis\x86\
2023-02-08 17:58:05,157 [3915812]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 28 - emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis\x86\
2023-02-08 17:58:05,157 [3915812]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 28 - Could not launch 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe': Invalid argument
2023-02-08 17:58:05,188 [3915843]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 28 - Process finished with exit code 22
2023-02-08 17:58:06,146 [3916801]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\Admin\.android\avd\Pixel_6_API_28.avd\hardware-qemu.ini.lock\pid not found for Pixel_6_API_28
2023-02-08 17:58:06,146 [3916801]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\Admin\.android\avd\Pixel_6_API_28.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Pixel_6_API_28
2023-02-08 17:58:06,147 [3916802]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_6_API_28 is online, assuming it's not
2023-02-08 17:58:08,375 [3919030]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appDebuggerSettings took 93 ms, DontShowAgainFeedbackService took 16 ms, FileTypeManager took 16 ms, FindSettings took 15 ms, LafManager took 16 ms, PropertyService took 31 ms, XDebuggerSettings took 15 ms
2023-02-08 17:58:08,563 [3919218]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=First Application, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=E:\Software\Android\FirstApplication)CompilerConfiguration took 16 ms, GradleSettings took 16 ms, RunManager took 15 ms, StructureViewFactory took 16 ms
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. In Review I rejected an edit to this question, as it's inappropriate. SE sites aren't discussion forums, issues aren't marked "SOLVED", but helpful answers are [accepted](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). The right way to mark this solved is to write the solution into an answer [even if you solved it yourself](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer), then accept the answer. I'd suggest taking the quick [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the Asking and Answering in [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to get a handle on how the site works :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but the solution is that MPFlat.dll is a core part of the android studio emulator all you have to do is download MPFlat.dll and add it to your emulator directory
`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\`
Download MPFlat.dll from [this](https://www.dll-files.com/mfplat.dll.html) link

Also run this command in your emulator directory:
`emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_4_API_33 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300`

But change the `Pixel_4_API_33` to the emulator you created on android studio

Comment: This is bad advice for one reason.  Downloading unpackaged DLLs from internet because someone said it is good is a gamble.  `MPFlat.dll` comes from the `Windows Media Feature pack` and only fails to exist in Windows N versions.  If indeed this is the problem, it should be installed from [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack) and not dll-files.com.

Comment: OP mentioned Windows 8 and not 10 which I referenced in the prev comment.  Windows 8 media feature pack can be found here:  [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744)